# Need help identifying stem, replacing tub stem assembly 1920s

Tags: plumbing, valve, bathroom-fixtures, old-house

Trying to replace two stem assemblies from what appears to be original 1920s tub as they are leaking. Bonnet of one stem is rounded so is stuck (separate issue). The other one I pulled out and am trying to match it. Local plumbing supply said it's likely American Standard but he can't find it in his catalogs. 6" in length, 1" width, 3/8" broach, 22 spline. I think maybe it's AS 59301. Anyone recognize this? Thanks for any advice.

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE 11/19: Ok, so I tried an American Standard 59301 and it seems to fit, but two issues after installation. When turning clockwise (to close) it doesn't stop spinning, counter clockwise (to open) reaches a point where it stops. More importantly, when opened up, water pours out of the center of the valve (around the stem).  I'm hoping it's an installation error and not a problem with the new part. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks [image]

[image]

Comment: Try a different plumbing supply house? Do they have anything close that would fit? Might they offer advice/parts to fix the existing one?

Comment: The one I went to didn't have anything close - mine was wider than any option they had. Will see if other suppliers have any ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Definitely old American Standard. There are replacement valves/stems available but I urge you to find a good plumbing shop (**NOT** the "big box stores) and take your existing valve to the shop to compare, as there are like 3 that are similar. You won't find it by searching the internet or calling around with dimensions, spline count, etc. [Larsen Supply](https://www.lasco.net/old-pdf-catalog-ezp-11)

[image]

Comment: Matching ceramic knobs are available still, too.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: At @Eagles22, since you took the [tour], you know that the proper way to say "thanks" is to up vote and accept (click the check mark) answers that help you.

Comment: Thanks. Site says I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote.